# ssh forwarding to master/slave nodes

Tags: ssh, forwarding

With putty and pageant, I want to login to a master node and from that, I want to ssh to an agent. The forwarding is enabled in the putty options. I can ssh to the master without password prompt. However, from master to slave, it asks for password. Although the public key is not present in the authorized_keys of the slave, I expect that forwarding do the same thing. Isn't that?

```
login as: vagrant
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20180330" from agent
Last login: Fri Mar 30 17:15:53 2018 from 192.168.65.1
[vagrant@m1 ~]$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAgcwqaj7nbho7I6yNPZTsMx/VkKDzmRksJ5POHdvpPdtKvukRHvBpNVWwL1K0bq2lzrYNqqGPkvPr7s8R5h9m+bEFP2suwW2lVvNnCB9hdNB5al3x3cK1MtYERUrpTCaocMZY2CM8y+ccZzSJ68qHalLatDtd9d5NY0LRztHSK/yB1elALSK13Qo9wYfYByGLx3eFtdczelHfG7a7TKOBPuFaYoLIpGyvK9woTQTcW6gasdl3pkYzx7Az8ij9skuxsuHeqXqgRc4B73tNCkXbgbkTohEaYPFQ/jZ1Lk2tPM79PWbZyW0AVxMWTgK+IahmAOh3ZmOFbNEmLEEGOwPfLw== rsa-key-20180330
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC7K1ldqJbAYzFsrGcDJe5xf1UyiCwTrvyn8K4GSRTxaam35dduZIAb1c5rpDs0OHfASTCrBXDu1bZXQIHNeskhLyGrDZ3mffomptwcr66YvPylGtpT8+XfSZD7YbyANB+7bTP8jrUD78dqllVbQqRFGVN0QeDTy9cJ/Yekv6p19WNRu+bMpfg0xwH0hF5L7njO7QKRpFqG2gRmkJL1W1OlBTBsCs+4gD+LCdRmKXWaTeNvfhdkLFFTdGnWaKpk09HgN7Y8UYjAIOW8+rd8wXD3W6XWU7laugCggI+p1pP27tJNnxK5QuIaR+asNRW5UJ0MhjYRTVABoXhw6DgaqN5f vagrant
[vagrant@m1 ~]$ ssh -A a1
vagrant@a1's password:
Last login: Fri Mar 30 17:16:15 2018 from 192.168.65.90
[vagrant@a1 ~]$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC7K1ldqJbAYzFsrGcDJe5xf1UyiCwTrvyn8K4GSRTxaam35dduZIAb1c5rpDs0OHfASTCrBXDu1bZXQIHNeskhLyGrDZ3mffomptwcr66YvPylGtpT8+XfSZD7YbyANB+7bTP8jrUD78dqllVbQqRFGVN0QeDTy9cJ/Yekv6p19WNRu+bMpfg0xwH0hF5L7njO7QKRpFqG2gRmkJL1W1OlBTBsCs+4gD+LCdRmKXWaTeNvfhdkLFFTdGnWaKpk09HgN7Y8UYjAIOW8+rd8wXD3W6XWU7laugCggI+p1pP27tJNnxK5QuIaR+asNRW5UJ0MhjYRTVABoXhw6DgaqN5f vagrant
[vagrant@a1 ~]$
```

Any configuration missed here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agent forwarding enables the "middle" ssh server to forward the key you're using to the next server you're contacting. It doesn't magically make the next server decide to allow that key access. Like with any other key, you need to set up the "slave" server to actually allow it, by including it in the authorized_key file for the account you're connecting with.